# WCF can have server and clients running different framework versions (2.0 & 4.0)(c# 3.5 and c# 4.0)

Tags: c#, wcf

WCF can have server and clients running different framework versions (2.0 & 4.0)(c# 3.5 and c# 4.0)?

I have a server alreary running WCF and several clients,   I am modifing the server side adding new funcionality but recompiling for the new framework (4.0),   the code part for the WCF was not changed ,   do I need to also recompile and migrate the clients to the new framework or they will work without any problem?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the contract didn't change that the client will interface with, it doesn't matter.